# return indices from filtered, sorted array with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, indexing

What is the most straightforward way to do the following in python/numpy?

- begin with random array `x`
- filter out elements `x < .5`
- sort the remaining values by size
- return indices of (original) `x` corresponding to these values

Comment: Did any of the solutions work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution:

- created sorted index array (argsort)
- create mask for sorted `x` less than threshold
- apply mask to sorted index array

example:

```
import numpy as np

# x = np.random.rand(4)
x = np.array([0.96924269, 0.30592608, 0.03338015, 0.64815553])
solution = np.array([2, 1])

sorted_idx = np.argsort(x)
idx_mask = (x[sorted_idx] < 0.5)
sorted_filtered_idx = sorted_idx[idx_mask]

assert np.all(sorted_filtered_idx == solution)
```

Answer (score 11):

Finding the mask of `x < 0.5` and `x.argsort()` seemed like compulsory here. Once you have those two, you can sort the mask array using the sort indices and use this mask on the sort indices to get back the indices corresponding to sorted indices that satisfy the masked condition. Thus, you would be adding one more line of code, like so -

```
mask = x < 0.5
sort_idx = x.argsort()
out = sort_idx[mask[sort_idx]]
```

Sample step-by-step run -

```
In [56]: x
Out[56]: array([ 0.8974009 ,  0.30127187,  0.71187137,  0.04041124])

In [57]: mask
Out[57]: array([False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [58]: sort_idx
Out[58]: array([3, 1, 2, 0])

In [59]: mask[sort_idx]
Out[59]: array([ True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [60]: sort_idx[mask[sort_idx]]
Out[60]: array([3, 1])
```

Answer (score 3):

Masked arrays are concise (but maybe not especially efficient)

```
x = np.random.rand(4);

inverse_mask = x < 0.5
m_x = np.ma.array(x, mask=np.logical_not(inverse_mask))
sorted_indeces = m_x.argsort(fill_value=1)
filtered_sorted_indeces = sorted_indeces[:np.sum(inverse_mask)]
```

Answer (score 0):

While the original query asks for the "most straightforward" approach, the provided answers don't filter the array first and then sort only the remainder as posed.  Sadly Numpy does not make this easy.

[AGN Glazer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8033585/agn-gazer) in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48435149/2783487) provides:

```
def meth_agn_v2(x, thresh):
    idx, = np.where(x > thresh)
    return idx[np.argsort(x[idx])]
```

but `np.where` does not support the `axis=` argument so this can't be generalized to multidimensional arrays like `np.argsort` (at least not that I can see).

For a small number of results `num`, [Ari Cooper-Davis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68612359/2783487) led me to this result:

```
sortedPosns = [n for n in range(num)]
b = numpy.argpartition(x, sortedPosns)
```

The result array b provides the first `num` indexes for the input array `x` in sorted order, but you have to provide the expected number of sorted entries.  The remaining indexes in b will have undefined order.