# Efficient numpy argsort with condition while maintaining original indices

Tags: python, numpy

I'm wondering what the most efficient way to do an argsort of an array given a condition, while preserving the original index

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0.63, 0.5, 0.7, 0.65])

np.argsort(x)
#Corrected argsort(x) solution
Out[99]: array([1, 0, 3, 2])
```

I want to argsort this array with condition that x>0.6. Since 0.5 < 0.6, index 1 should not be included.

```
x = np.array([0.63, 0.5, 0.7, 0.65])
index = x.argsort()
list(filter(lambda i: x[i] > 0.6, index))

[0,3,2]
```

This is inefficient since its not vectorized.

EDIT:
The filter will eliminate most of elements. So ideally, it filter first, then sort, while preserving original index.

Comment: Also what do you mean by efficient? Big O efficient? If so the answer depends on `x` and the theshold value (`0.5`).

Comment: To be clear, what do you expect from `x = np.array([0.63, 0.5, 0.7, 0.65])`? `np.argsort(x)[x > 0.6] = [1, 3, 2]` but `x[1] < 0.6`

Comment: Like @jp_data_analysis mentioned, np.argsort(x)[x > 0.5] doesn't work. I want to preserve the original index of x.

Comment: Check out `v2` in my answer - it is likely the most efficient (so far).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Method 1 (Same idea as Tai's method but using integer indexing)

Too late to the party too and if my solution is a repeat of an already posted solution - ping me and I will delete it.

```
def meth_agn_v1(x, thresh):
    idx = np.arange(x.size)[x > thresh]
    return idx[np.argsort(x[idx])]
```

Then,

```
In [143]: meth_agn_v1(x, 0.5)
Out[143]: array([0, 3, 2])
```

### Method 2 (significant performance improvement)

This uses the same idea expressed in the last section of my answer (comparison to Tai's method) that integer indexing is faster than boolean indexing (for small number of expected elements to be selected) and avoids creating an initial index at all.

```
def meth_agn_v2(x, thresh):
    idx, = np.where(x > thresh)
    return idx[np.argsort(x[idx])]
```

### Timing

```
In [144]: x = np.random.rand(100000)

In [145]: timeit meth_jp(x, 0.99)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.43 ms per loop

In [146]: timeit meth_alex(x, 0.99)
1000 loops, best of 3: 498 µs per loop

In [147]: timeit meth_tai(x, 0.99)
1000 loops, best of 3: 298 µs per loop

In [148]: timeit meth_agn_v1(x, 0.99)
1000 loops, best of 3: 232 µs per loop

In [161]: timeit meth_agn_v2(x, 0.99)
10000 loops, best of 3: 95 µs per loop
```

### Comparison of v1 to Tai's method

My first version of the answer is very similar to Tai's answer but not identical.

Tai's method as published originally:

```
def meth_tai(x, thresh):
    y = np.arange(x.shape[0])
    y = y [x > thresh]  
    x = x [x > thresh] # x = x[y] is used in my method
    y[np.argsort(x)]
```

So, my method is different in using integer array indexing instead of the boolean indexing used by Tai. For a small number of selected elements integer indexing is faster than boolean indexing making this method more efficient than Tai's method even after Tai optimized his code.

Comment: @Tai You are right - the two methods are pretty similar but differ in the kind of indexing used to select elements to be sorted. I added a new section that compares the two methods.

Comment: @Tai I just added a much better version to my answer. Check it out.

Comment: @Tai Many Thanks! No need to upvote. "Coold optimization" was good enough for me!

Comment: Nice work with the `np.where`. This should be the selected answer.

Comment: @Alex Nice of you [holder of selected answer] to say this! Thank you for appreciating this approach.

Comment: This is great - Method 2 is at least an order of magnitude faster

Answer (score 6):

Come a bit late to the party. The idea is that we can sort an array based on sorted indices of another array.

```
y = np.arange(x.shape[0]) # y for preserving the indices
mask = x > thresh
y = y[mask]  
x = x[mask]
ans = y[np.argsort(x)]    # change order of y based on sorted indices of x
```

The method is to add an array `y` that is just for recording the indices of `x`. We then filter out both arrays based on the boolean indexes `x > thresh`. Then, sort `x` with `argsort`. Finally, use the indices return by `argsort` to change the order of `y`!

Comment: This is clean - nice.

Answer (score 3):

#### Method 1 (@jp_data_analysis answer)

You should use this one unless you have reason not to.

```
def meth1(x, thresh):
    return np.argsort(x)[(x <= thresh).sum():]
```

#### Method 2

If the filter will greatly reduce the number of elements in the array and the array is large then following may help:

```
def meth2(x, thresh):
    m = x > thresh
    idxs = np.argsort(x[m])
    offsets = (~m).cumsum()
    return idxs + offsets[m][idxs]
```

#### Speed comparison

```
x = np.random.rand(10000000)

%timeit meth1(x, 0.99)
# 2.81 s ± 244 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit meth2(x, 0.99)
# 104 ms ± 1.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: I disagree with this method. Consider `x = np.array([0.63, 0.5, 0.7, 0.65])`. With `x > 0.6` condition, both methods give `[1, 3, 2]`. Yet `x[1] = 0.5 < 0.6`. Or have I misread the question?

Comment: np.argsort(x)[x > 0.6] doesn't preserve the original index.

Comment: Brilliant! The filter eliminates ~90% of the elements, so method 2 is better.
My test results: Method 1 is 16.4ms , Method 2 is 2.24 ms

Comment: @Alex, we were both deleting at the same time! I'm happy if yours is accepted since you've described it better, and came up with the better algorithm for high threshold.

Comment: Cool method too!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more hackish approach which modifies the original array with some arbitrary maximum number which will not likely to occur in the original array.

```
In [50]: x = np.array([0.63, 0.5, 0.7, 0.65])
In [51]: invmask = ~(x > 0.6)

# replace it with some huge number which will not occur in your original array
In [52]: x[invmask] = 9999.0

In [53]: np.argsort(x)[:-sum(invmask)]
Out[53]: array([0, 3, 2])
```

Comment: While this may do the trick, it would be very inefficient because it is sorting the entire array. According to OP, the filter eliminates most elements.